# Toast is not rendered (react-toastify component)

Tags: reactjs, toast

I'm using `react-toastify` and I can't get a simple toast to be rendered...

```
import React from "react";
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

class MyView extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {

        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        toast("Hello", { autoClose: false });
    }

    notify = () => toast("Hello", { autoClose: false });

    render() {
        return (
           <div>
             <button onClick={this.notify}>Notify</button>
           </div>
      )}
}
```

package.json (in "dependencies" section)

```
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-toastify": "^3.2.2"
```

If I debug it, I see that my toasts are queued, _EventManager2 never gets the _constant.ACTION.MOUNTED event that normally emits the toasts from the queue...

```
/**
 * Wait until the ToastContainer is mounted to dispatch the toast
 * and attach isActive method
 */
_EventManager2.default.on(_constant.ACTION.MOUNTED, function (containerInstance) {
  container = containerInstance;

  toaster.isActive = function (id) {
    return container.isToastActive(id);
  };

  queue.forEach(function (item) {
    _EventManager2.default.emit(item.action, item.content, item.options);
  });
  queue = [];
});
```

..so there might be something wrong with that ToastContainer but what? I just use the sample code from the documentation.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: have you placed the <ToastContainer /> ?

Answer (score 104):

You have to also `import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';`

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
  import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
  // minified version is also included
  // import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css';
 
  class App extends Component {
    notify = () => toast("Wow so easy !");
 
    render(){
      return (
        <div>
        <button onClick={this.notify}>Notify !</button>
          <ToastContainer />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Adding the CSS file and making sure that the <ToastContainer /> is being used in your component made the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Before declaring your class, add the following line:

```
toast.configure();
```

Comment: OP indicated that the response given in comments helped him solve the problem. Then, someone created an answer from that advice and it received 14 upvotes, with a comment that, again, indicated it was the correct solution. What does your answer have to offer?

Comment: It's just an alternative option stated in the documentation: https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify#what-if-i-told-you-that-the-toastcontainer-is-optional

Comment: @chb that isn't how Stack Exchange works. It's not acceptable to post the same answer twice, but it's completely acceptable to post a different solution. Oftentimes the second answer turns out to be better than the first

Comment: @StephenLead My comment relates to the quality of the response, not its uniqueness or how much it differs from others offered. It's a one-line answer that does nothing to explain what that one line does, or how it might be better than what's already been proposed.

Comment: @chb fair enough, it could be expanded for clarity

Answer (score 12):

install react-toastify using command

```sh
npm i react-toastify
```

Then:

```js
import {ToastContainer,toast} from 'react-toastify'
```

and in return add

```js
<ToastContainer />
```

and after that when you do `toast('hy')`
then it will show toast

Answer (score 9):

Even better, import minified css:

`import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css';`

or in case you are importing it in .scss file

`@import '~react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css';`

Comment: this is the better answer b/c it imports the file in the scss file rather than tsx

Answer (score 5):

The other solutions didn't work for me - turns out I wasn't passing a string to the `toast.*` function. For example:

```
  getSomethingFromApi()
     .then((response) =>  { 
         // this works fine because response.message is a string
         toast.notify(response.message)
      })
     .catch((error) => {
         // this will fail to render because error is an object, not a string
         toast.error(error)
      })
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough. Was dealing with this for last two days.

Comment: Geez, this took me a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For me moving `ReactToastify.css` above `toast`  solved the issue!

```
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'; // import first
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify'; // then this
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remember to include the `<ToastContainer />` in your render.

Answer (score 2):

Tried everything here but nothing work then I move the following lines in App.js then it start working.

```
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to import this CSS statement in the component that you want to render the toastify at

```
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was importing toast without {} curly braces because my course instructor did so.

Try to change this:

```
    import toast from 'react-toastify';
```

To:

```
    import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
```

Also according to all other 'react-toastify' stackoverflow responses, installing latest version causes problem. So try uninstalling it and install older version that your course instructor did or version 4.1 seems to be working for most people.
Uninstall first:

```
    npm uninstall react-toastify --save
```

Then install 4.1 version:

```
    npm i react-toastify@4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

To make use of the react-toastify, Please follow below steps:-

1. Install the npm package

   npm i toastify --save
2. Import the react-toastify as shown below in that given order

   import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'; // import first

   import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify'; // then this

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import { ToastContainer,toast } from 'react-toastify'; // <- add ToastContainer
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'; // <- add line 

class MyView extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {

        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        toast("Hello", { autoClose: false });
    }

    notify = () => toast("Hello", { autoClose: false });

    render() {
        return (
           <div>
             <button onClick={this.notify}>Notify</button>
             <ToastContainer /> {/* <- add line */}
           </div>
      )}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
// React-Tostify configuration

import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

import {ToastContainer} from "react-toastify";
```

maintain this order
and include `<ToastContainer />` in return
This worked for me!